# Automated Unit Testing of C++

Tags: unit-testing

Is there any way to generate automated unit test cases for c++ code written using VS2005. I do some basic R&D and found that there is a support for automated testing in VS2005 but its only for Managed Code, so i am looking for something specific to:
       "Automatic generation of Test cases of Native C++ Code"
It doesn't matter whether its a plug-in that works with VS2005 or any standalone application. But it is preferred to have some plug-in sort of solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if you are asking about a unit testing framework (if yes, try [cppUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cppunit)), or if you really want tests code-generated.  If the latter, I imagine the answer is no.  Usually a capability like that is linked to reflection and/or built-in design-by-contract capabilities (e.g Eiffel or C# with .net 4.0).